# Dropdown not binding in IE 8

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am binding dropdown list using jquery and asp.net callbacks.

this is working in IE-9,11 and other browsers also but It is not working in IE-8.

and It is not showing any error also.

I am using bellow javascript function for binding dropdown

```
function ClientCallback(result, context) {
        if (!$('#ddltest')) {
            return;
        }
        $('#ddltest').length = 0;
        if (!result) {
            return;
        }
        $(result).find('Table1').each(function () {
            var OptionValue = $(this).find('OptionText').text();
            var OptionText = $(this).find('OptionText').text();
            var option = $("<option>" + OptionText + "</option>");
            option.attr("value", OptionValue);
            $('#ddltest').append(option);
        });
    }
```

from code behind method I am returning dataset in the form of xml like return ds.GetXml();

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: You probably use the jQuery version that is not suppoer IE8.

Comment: What is the version number of jquery you use ?

Comment: I checked in console also there is no error.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.4.1.js

Comment: @suresh use a version above 1.9 there are some cases reported for jquery below 1.9 not working in ie6,7and8

Comment: @Arvin I checked using jquery-1.11.2.js version but It's not working.

Comment: OK, so do you know which bit is not working -  does it exit by using one of the returns or doe sit get as far as going inside the each loop? Does it create the element to append?  I would help if possible if you could narrow down it down to a single line of code? You could add some console.log() messages and then poly fill this for IE8 like http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/ ...  If you don't want to use a polyfill, you could simply return an integer so that you know which branch it took out of your code.